# Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input' (I already did the import)

Tags: angular

I have this component:

```
import { Component, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CoursesService } from './courses.service';



@Component({
    selector: 'courses',
    template: `
        <input [(ngModel)]="email" (keyup.enter)="onKeyUp()" />
    `
})

export class CoursesComponent { 

    email = "test@outlook.com";

    onKeyUp(){
        console.log();
    }

}
```

getting this error for the [(ngModel)] : Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

I have already imported it in my app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CoursesComponent } from './courses.component';
import { CoursesService } from './courses.service';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CoursesComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [
    CoursesService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

do you have any solutions ?  thanks

Comment: has you "re-start" the ng serve? (sometimes you need re-start it when add modules to the main.module.ts)

Comment: yea.. I rerun the application multiple times.. i also closed vs code but not working 
I just realized that ngFor is not working too.. (the same reason)

Comment: try rewrite the imports (sometimes we write an "strange character" that we can not see in the editor) Sorry I'm not imagine no more :(